# Can Siri custom intents display custom UI for every input parameter?

Tags: ios, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

From the below description from Apple's documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/creating_an_intents_ui_extension/configuring_the_view_controller_for_your_custom_interface

> Although SiriKit often passes only one parameter at a time to your configureView(for:of:interactiveBehavior:context:completion:) method, you can configure a view that displays content for any number of parameters. When calling the completion handler of your configuration method, provide SiriKit with the set of parameters that your interface displays. Before creating a new view controller with the next set of parameters, SiriKit checks to see if you already displayed those parameters. If you did, SiriKit does not ask you to display them again.

I was expecting a call to the `configureView` method on following situations

1. before the user has provided any parameter inputs. This time INParameter list will be empty
2. before asking each parameter input from the user. So we can decide whether to show a custom UI for that input or allow siri to show it's default UI.

So I have created a custom intent (of category **Order**) which accepts 3 parameters. And a custom UI has to be shown to the user during every input parameter.

But call to the `configureView` method happens only once after the user providing all the input parameters. So always the default UI from Siri has been displayed. Also the  INParameter list is empty.

Is it possible to show custom UI for every input parameter ? Or is this limited only to the system intents ?

I am testing with iOS 13.

Comment: Can you post your custom UIs as well to get more idea about what kind of UI you are trying to display?

Comment: For example, I want to show a list of items in a collection view for the user to select. Right now, Siri is displaying the list in a simple table view with the "displayString" only. But I would like to show icons and more details to these items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is No.

I have received following answer from apple forum.
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/126861

> You can only customize the view for the confirm and handle phases of
>   handling an intent -- you can't customize the UI during the resolution
>   of a value for a parameter. This is true of both system and custom
>   intents.